# is there any way to apply different class in the forloop of Jinja template

Tags: jinja2

i'm an beginer to Jinja. I have a problem when i want to apply different style in Jinja forloop. I had searched the web but couldn't find a solution.

In python i pass a list to Jinja template as below:

```
my_list = [
    {"Message": "this is sender message",
     "Des": 1
    },
    { "Message": "this is receiver message",
      "Des": 0
    } ]

...
render_template(
    messages = my_list
    )
```

In template, i want to apply different style according to message.Des .

```
{% for message in messages %}
{% if message.Des==1 %}
    <div class="sender_message">
{% else %}
    <div class="receiver_message">
{% endif %}

    <div>
        <img src={{ url_for("static", filename="img/info.jpg") }} width="36px" height="36px">
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>
            {{message.Message}}
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But, as the forloop doesn't support continue/break, above code doesn't work.

Here I want to know, is there a way to implement the same function? Many thanks to you!

Comment: I guess you meant `class="receiver_message"` in the else block. Anyway, what does this if-else construction have to do with Jinja not supporting loop breaks?

Comment: Thanks, @makeiteasy. Yes, you're right, it should be receiver_message. My purpose is to implement a diagram view, for sender_message, text and pictures will be left alignment by apply this sytle in css, and for receiver_message, it will be right alignment.
this should be a common requirement i think, I guess there must have some way to do this in Jinja,  but i just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I may find the solution. I perform a forloop in python code which covert the message.Des to string "sender_message" or "receiver_message" before pass my_list to Jinjia. Then it's no need to do IF instruction in Jinja template. I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it works for me.

Comment: From what I can see you can just do `<div class="{{ "sender_message" if message.Des is equalto 1 else "receiver_message" }}">`. There's no need to duplicate repeated part.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different styles based on the message.Des value. Use the variable as your div id value.

Here is the code.

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message.Des==1 %}
        <div class="sender_message">
    {% else %}
        <div class="receiver_message">
    {% endif %}

        <div>
            <img src={{ url_for("static", filename="img/info.jpg") }} width="36px" height="36px">
        </div>
        <div id={{message.Des}}>
            <pre>
                {{message.Message}}
            </pre>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```